# XAMPP 7.4.8-installation new, but pear-errors "curly braces"

Tags: php, xampp, pear, braces

I installed xampp   Win32, Version 7.4.8 (also  tried 8.0).
I had errors when i installed phplicensewatcher, here: Missing HTML/Table, or HTML/Common...

So i tried to install it with
pear install HTML_Table in XAMPP-Console, but it fails  with

```
 # pear install HTML_Table
PHP Fatal error:  Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is no longer supported in C:\xampp2\php\pear\PEAR\Config.php on line 2095

Fatal error: Array and string offset access syntax with curly braces is no longer supported in C:\xampp2\php\pear\PEAR\Config.php on line 2095
```

So i saw, that many files there hold "{0}" instead of "[0]", file are dated from  2016.

What can i do?

Thanks
Bernhard

Answer (score 0):

Thats because this:

https://wiki.php.net/rfc/deprecate_curly_braces_array_access

Let's say you have something like this in your code:

```
$str = "test";
echo($str{0});
```

since PHP 7.4 curly braces method to get individual characters inside a string has been deprecated, so change the above syntax into this:

```
$str = "test";
echo($str[0]);
```